# I can't use my mouse whenever one program is frozen

Tags: 16.04, mouse

I'm working with a large spreadsheet that often causes libreoffice to become unresponsive. When that happens I get a spinning wheel for a cursor and whenever that happens I can't click with my mouse at all. I can't really avoid libreoffice from unresponsive but I'd like to be able to use my mouse while it's unresponsive. Does anyone know how to make it so I can click with my mouse while one program is unresponsive?

Comment: My suggestion is upgrade the machine.

Comment: Without further detail it's impossible to determine what exactly is causing your system to become unresponsive. It could be for example CPU bound (high load), experiencing high iowait, or imminent  drive failure to name a few. Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and try to be a bit more specific. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: My system isn't becoming unresponsive it's just one program (libreoffice) that is being unresponsive. It's unresponsive because I'm doing an operation on a massive spreadsheet. My problem is when one program becomes unresponsive I can't use my mouse.